# Unable to create a session using CGI BIN

Tags: perl

I am new to this perl scripting i have got the below error when i tried viewing a webpage.
please let me know what may be the cause for this.

i have tried the following but it didn't work

1. set the env variable path using PERL5LIB
2. copying the Session.pm to another location
3. giving full permission to all the files and directories

ERROR:

> [error] [client 192.168.0.12] Can't locate CGI/Session.pm in @INC
>   (@INC contains: .) at /var/www/cgi-bin/CP/vacation.pl line 7., [error]
>   [client 192.168.0.12] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /var/www/cgi-bin/CP/vacation.pl line 7.,  [error] [client
>   192.168.0.12] Premature end of script headers: vacation.pl,

Code part where it is showing error is marked bold :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

##use strict;

# Exports
use CGI qw/:standard/;
***use CGI::Session;***
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); ## NOTE: For development purposes.. remove it when deploying
use Sys::Hostname;
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::Local;

require "ebackup.pl" ;

# Global variables
my $send_mail_perl = "/ERecaller/Temp/swaks.pl";

## Server Settings File
my $ipconfig = "/ERecaller/ConfigurationDB/Data/ercl_config_server.txt";
```

Comment: Does your error really say `(@INC contains: .)`??? There should be at least two other paths in there. Something's wrong with your Perl!

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote ("copying the Session.pm to another location"), I suppose you simply copied Session.pm into directory with your program. It will not work this way, you should install it (there are other options, but they are more complex). Do "cpan CGI::Session" as root, or use something like local::lib if you can't do it (or ask for it).

Comment: i have installed  the module which i downloaded from CPAN website .

Comment: Did you install it globally or to some local directory?